# jQuery-ui datepicker gets cut off when scroll bar exists

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, datepicker

[image: Imgur]
[image: Imgur]

Here is a screenshot of what I'm experiencing. The dark teal band at the bottom of the picture is a footer that spans across the whole screen, and what is inside the white area with the portion of the table that you see is an iframe that displays a page. When the page the iframe displays has a lot of content, the scroll bar appears, and causes an issue for the datepickers in the last few rows of the table.

The first image shows what it looks like when the datepicker input isn't focused. The scrollbar for the iframe is there. When I focus the datepicker input, it seems to create more space at the bottom of the page for the datepicker to be displayed in, however when I click/drag the scroll bar down to view the bottom of the datepicker, the datepicker disappears/glitches out and then it goes back to the state in screenshot 1. What's weird is that when I focus the datepicker input, I am able to use the mousewheel to scroll down and view the rest of the calendar. It's just clicking/dragging the scroll bar to view it that makes it go away.